# Assign value to textfield firstview take of secondview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have two views in my application: in main view there are input fields that the user must fill and a button connected to the second view. In the second view there is a table view, when the user selects a row automatically returns to the main view.
My problem is that when you return to the main view the values ​​of text fields are cleared.
Any solutions?
Thank you.

Second View header

```
    @class MainViewController;

    @interface ListaViewController : UIViewController 
    <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
    {
       UITableView *table;
       UISearchBar *search;
       MainViewController *child;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *child;


    - (IBAction)switchBack:(id)sender;
```

Second View Implementation:

```
      -(IBAction)switchBack:(id)sender 
      {
        child.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
        child.codiceComune = codiceComune;
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      }
```

First View:

```
      -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
      {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        cityField.text = selectedCountry;
      }
```

This not work!

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(IBAction)switchBack:(id)sender 
      {
         MainViewController *controller = [[MainViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated: YES];
        [controller release];
      }
```

It means you create **new** MainViewController, not return to previous.

Use this code instead

```
-(IBAction)switchBack:(id)sender  
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

P.S. It works if you go to the second vievcontroller same way, as you write in `-(IBAction)switchBack:(id)sender`

Comment: Thk, but i have a problem, i passed value to main view with controller.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
controller.code = code;

Comment: @Maurizio It means that you doing things wrong. You dont need to create new MainController, just change this values in previous. For example, you can send your MainController as variable in SecondView and change his properties before dismiss.

Comment: thk. how to assign values ​​to the first view by taking the value from the second view? If i use simple dismiss not work.

Comment: @Maurizio Add MainViewController *parent; and @property(nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *parent in secondView.h, synthesyze it. Then after it's initialise before it's present set this property to your original MainView. Something like [secondView setParent:self] in MainView's method, calling secondView. And finally in -(IBAction)switchBack:(id)sender before dismiss put parent.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
parent.code = code; And don't forget release parrent in dealloc method

Comment: Thk, please see up my code. I think there is a problem because cityField.txt  not have value.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess without code, you're probably emptying or initialising your text fields in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear or viewWillappear - do it in your viewController init instead.

Comment: You are recreating your viewcontroller. Which is recreating your text fields. You need to switch back to your original viewController not recreate it.